# circle detection in open cv using python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I was trying to detect circles from a black background with red circular kind objects.

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('extracted.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                        param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint8(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
   # draw the outer circle
   cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
   # draw the center of the circle
   cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have loaded the image in grayscale mode,still it gives me an error

```
"circles = np.uint8(np.around(circles))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2277, in around
  return _wrapit(a, 'round', decimals, out)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 37, in _wrapit
  result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: rint"
```

I cannot post the image because of my present reputation.

Comment: plz ignore the indentation errors

Comment: try this code : https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/houghcircles.py

Comment: Abid thanks, I tried the code but it gives me cv2.circle(cimg, (circles[0][i][0], circles[0][i][1]), circles[0][i][2], (0, 0, 255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LINE_AA'

Comment: Just remove that `cv2.LINE_AA`.

Comment: thanks a lot Abid, it worked. How can I set the minimum and maximum radius to be detected? means which parameter indicates it?

Comment: may be last two, please check documentation : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#cv2.HoughCircles

Comment: okay I think I got it. Its the line circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, np.array([]), 100, 30, 0, 0), where the lat two parameters indicate min and max radii. Thanks a lot

Comment: OK, then I will post it as answer, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark next to it, so that you can close this session.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a small correction to be made in your code.

You are loading image in grayscale, and then again converting it to grayscale using `cv2.cvtColor` which is invalid operation.

Alternatively, OpenCV provides a [sample for circle detection using Hough Circles method](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/houghcircles.py). You can try that.

If you are using OpenCV 2.x version, just change the `cv2.LINE_AA` to `cv2.CV_AA` or any other lineType you prefer.

Comment: The link you posted is dead.